# How to add additional minutes to displayed time from datepicker

Tags: swift, xcode

So i have datepicker and label that displaying selected time, but i need to make it like that. For example, i selected 10:00 time and label should show 11:30 13:00 14:30. Whatever time you pick it should be +1.5h +3h +4.5h. What i have to do?

```
@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var DPOne: UIDatePicker!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    hoursMinutes()
    DPOne.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateChanged), for: .valueChanged)
    
}

@objc func dateChanged() {
    hoursMinutes()
}


func hoursMinutes()  {
    
    let DF = DateFormatter()
    DF.timeStyle = .short
    let strDate = DF.string(from: DPOne.date)
    dateLabel.text = strDate
    

    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check these out: `DPOne.date.addingTimeInterval(...)`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1948745-addingtimeinterval

Comment: Good suggestion. (Voted.) Another option would be the Calendar method `date(byAdding:value:to:wrappingComponents:)`, but for adding a few hours using `Date.addingTimeInterval(_:)` is simpler and should be fine.